# Not all keys work when converting JSON String to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary, nsdata

I'm using the following code to convert a JSON string literal to an array holding an NSDictionary for each item:

```
NSString* json = @"[{\"name\":\"Item 1\",\"id\":\"999\",\"lang\":\"en\",\"type\":\"A\",\"version\":15}]";
NSData* data = [json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray* values = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

After removing the app from my test device, the app started crashing when attempting to access, in a `for` loop `values[i][@"name"]`. When viewing `values` in the inspector, I see the following:

```
values = (NSArray *) @"1 object"
    [0] = (__NSDictionaryM *) 5 key/value pairs
        [0] = (no summary) : @"Item 1"
        [1] = @"id" : @"999"
        [2] = @"type" : @"A"
        [3] = (no summary) : (long)15
        [4] = @"lang" : (no summary)
```

When expanded further, the keys that should be `name` and `version` are both shown to be the type `(__NSCFConstantString *)`

This was working prior to removing the app from the device, and no changes have been made to this section of the code.

Any ideas on what could be causing this, or better ways to convert the json string to a dictionary?

**UPDATE**: I changed "name" and "version" to "game" and "gersion", and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Working in what way? ArrYs are accessed by index not key, so you're saying your code has always been wrong.

Comment: Sorry, this is an array of dictionaries. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Why would you use a JSON string literal rather than an Objective-C array literal of dictionary literals? Anyway, log the array or, in the debugger, do `po values`.

Comment: @Ken Thomases This is data coming from a server, I just need to parse it. For testing I logged the JSON and copied the string so I don't need to continuously grab it from the server.

Comment: It sounds like you have a memory smasher bug.

Comment: 1) The Xcode debugger's variable inspector is highly unreliable.  Use NSLog or type `po` in the console window -- never trust the debugger's display.  2) If the data really is mucked up like that (and it's not a debugger artifact) then you have a bad storage bug (zombies).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After attempting to debug this for several hours, my supervisor and I decided to restart the MacBook I'm developing on. This resolved the runtime issue, and the code in my question is once again working as expected.

We are still unsure what caused the device to get into this state, since running "Clean Build Folder" several times, closing and relaunching XCode, and restarting the iPad did nothing to help us.

I considered removing the question, but since we don't know what caused this I figured someone else may run into this issue in the future and this answer could help them. If anyone could provide some insight into what may have brought this situation about, I will gladly accept your answer.

Comment: Did you run into this again in Xcode 12.1 per chance?  I'm getting the "(no summary)" for one double value not the other in an x/y plot scenario.