# Parse json to NSDictionary could not save correct

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

```
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10];

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
        NSString *str =[NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
        NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [request setHTTPBody:data];
        NSError *error;
        NSData *received = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

        NSDictionary *currencyDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:received options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

I want save json to `currencyDic`,but some data couldn't save at key

json:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "USD2JPY": 106.544998,
            "USD2SGD_ts": 1465039761,
            "USD2ITL_ts": 1434960300,
            "USD2FRF": 5.7601,
            "USD2GBP": 0.688942,
            "USD2MOP_ts": 1464990701,
            "USD2CHF": 0.975795,
            "USD2AUD_ts": 1465039761,
            "USD2EUR_ts": 1465039761,
            "USD2EUR": 0.879817,
            "USD2CNY_ts": 1465039761,
            "USD2HKD_ts": 1465039761,
            "USD2CAD_ts": 1465039761,
            "USD2ITL": 1700.272217,
            "USD2CHF_ts": 1465039761,
            "USD2DEM": 1.71745,
            "USD2DEM_ts": 1434958500,
            "USD2GBP_ts": 1465039761,
            "USD2JPY_ts": 1465039761,
            "USD2HKD": 7.7678,
            "USD2FRF_ts": 1434958260,
            "USD2CNY": 6.56645,
            "DATA_ts": 1465116640,
            "USD2AUD": 1.357589,
            "USD2MOP": 8.00155,
            "USD2CAD": 1.2938,
            "USD2SGD": 1.35655
        }
    ],
    "status": "ok"
}
```

and I use Xcode watch value

```
    currencyDic __NSDictionaryM *   2 key/value pairs   0x00007fc7ac35c110
    [0] (null)  (no summary) : (no summary) 
    [1] (null)  (no summary) : @"1 element" 
    key NSTaggedPointerString * 0xd D\x16F\x17\x06\0\0\xa0
    value   __NSArrayM *    @"1 element"    0x00007fc7ac35c0e0
    [0] __NSDictionaryM *   27 key/value pairs  0x00007fc7ac35c0b0
    [0] (null)  (no summary) : (double)0.975795 
    key NSTaggedPointerString * 0x0 W5E$3\x84d\xa4
    value   __NSCFNumber *  (double)0.975795    0x00007fc7ac330400
    [1] (null)  @"USD2JPY_ts" : (long)1465039761    
    [2] (null)  @"USD2FRF_ts" : (long)1434958260    
    key __NSCFString *  @"USD2FRF_ts"   \xf0\xbf5\xac\xc7\x7f\0\0
    value   __NSCFNumber *  (long)1434958260    0xb0000005587b9b43
        ........
```

All strings like  "USD2JPY" could not parse,just "no summary",but "USD2SGD_ts" can save into NSDictionary.  I try to change option(   `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` ),
   `NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves` ,
   `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments` )It's doesn't work.
How to fix it?Thanks

Comment: You ever find a solution for this?  Seems like this is happening in with Xcode 12.1 as well

Answer (score 0):

Xcode uses `-debugDescription` of the to print out objects. There are some optimizations in it to prevent the print-out of being too long. What is printed as "(no summary)" are simply strings of the class `NSTaggedPointerString`. But they are valid strings.

You should file a bug for this.

Comment: but if I use `NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves` the key is 0x0 is empty

Comment: *[…] the key is 0x0 is empty*? There is definitely no `nil` key in a dictionary. Maybe you should post the whole code.

Comment: but I receive a json file only use these code to parse json.And I trans json to a nsstring and output it.It's correct.

Comment: Of course, it is correct. *[…] the key is 0x0 is empty*? There is definitely no `nil` key in a dictionary. Maybe you should post the whole code.

Comment: At which location in your code do you get a `nil` value?

Comment: after `NSDictionary *currencyDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:received options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];`

Comment: Do you mean, that `currencyDic` is `nil`? This is no key. However, returning `nil` means, that an error occured. What is the content of `error`?

Comment: No,currencyDic is not nil. My watch is `[0] __NSDictionaryM *   27 key/value pairs  0x00007fc7ac35c0b0     [0] (null)  (no summary) : (double)0.975795`  just some string cannot parse,number is correct .

Comment: Man, at which location in your code do you get a nil value?

Comment: after save to dictionary.

Comment: I find the reason,but I can't fix it.[Like this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313411/debugger-is-only-showing-the-values-of-a-dictionary-and-no-summary-for-the-k)  If I run my program on 5S or some of 64bit devices，always 「no summary」,but if I run on 4S,every data are correct.